# Testing for view in MySQL before creating it

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to test for a MySQL v5.1 view, if it exists do not run the create code, if does not exist create the view. My code is as follows, but phpMyAdmin continually gives me one error after another. I’m attempting to build a view in this example named “nr0ad” which is also a value of the variable “netcall” in the st table. As written the error I get is

> #1054 - Unknown column '@viewnm' in 'where clause'

I get the same thing if I drop the tick marks around the variable @viewnm in any location.

Regardless of what changes I make to the @viewnm variable I get an error, does someone see a syntax error I’m making somewhere?

```
-- Check if the view exists
SET @viewnm = 'nr0ad';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.views
WHERE table_schema = 'ncm' AND table_name = `@viewnm`;

-- Create the view if it doesn't exist
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ncm.@viewnm AS
SELECT DISTINCT st.callsign, st.email, CONCAT(st.Fname, ' ', st.Lname, ' --> ', st.state, '--', st.county, '--', st.district) AS name
FROM ncm.stations st
JOIN ncm.NetLog nl ON st.callsign = nl.callsign
WHERE nl.netcall = `@viewnm`
  AND nl.logdate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  AND nl.logdate < CURRENT_DATE()
  AND nl.callsign NOT LIKE '%NONHAM%'
  AND nl.callsign NOT LIKE '%EMCOMM%';
```

This is how I set it up in PHP.  But it's still not working. Even though the created SQL looks good and works if dropped into phpMyAdmin.

```
<?PHP $q = 'CREW2273'; 

$sql = (
    "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ncm.$q AS
        SELECT DISTINCT st.callsign, st.Fname, 
            st.Lname, st.email, st.tactical, 
            st.latitude, st.longitude, st.grid, 
                st.county,   st.state,     st.city, 
                st.district, st.creds,     st.country, 
                CONCAT(st.Fname, ' ', st.Lname, ' --> ', st.state, '--', st.county, '--', st.district) AS name
          FROM ncm.stations st
          JOIN ncm.NetLog nl ON st.callsign = nl.callsign
         WHERE nl.netcall = '$q'
           AND nl.callsign NOT LIKE '%NONHAM%'
           AND nl.callsign NOT LIKE '%EMCOMM%'
           AND nl.logdate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
           AND nl.logdate < CURRENT_DATE()
           
    ");
        echo "<br>$sql<br>";
        
        $stmt = $db_found->prepare($sql);
        execute($stmt); 
?>
```

Comment: you can't use variables for names of tables, columns, views, etc. You will need to write a procedure that uses `PREPARE` to construct dynamic SQL.

Comment: I guess I didn't know that. I'm prepared to use PREPARE if I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify the variable name in the create view query directly , simply create a sql query and execute it using a prepare statement

```
SET @viewnm = 'nr0ad';

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW ', @viewnm, ' AS SELECT * FROM appt_tbl');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: how might this look in PHP?